# How to bind javascript variable to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have an object:

```
obj = {func1: function(){return $(h1)};} // notice, there is no $ defined anywhere...
```

And somewhere else I have a line

```
jq = require('jQuery');
```

Now want to write a function or something, that takes object and a jQuery as an argument and binds it so that I can do something like this:

```
obj2 = myBind(obj, jq);
obj2.func1(); // works
```

Comment: The `$` in your top line is relying on variable scope. So if the `require`  is coming from some other part of code, then you'd need to define `$` as a global variable. Or if they're in the same scope, then you can use a local one. But there isn't going to be any other way to associate `$` with `jq`.

Comment: if you're writing a plugin, in your document.ready call when you add it to the prototype you can use the special `$` var still.

Comment: though, if you don't have `$` defined anywhere, you can simply reassign `$ = jq;` after your `jq = require('jQuery');` line.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> obj = {func1: function(){return $(h1)};}
> ```
>
> notice, there is no $ defined anywhere...

Then it's going to stay undefined, unless you create such a variable in any parent scope (like the global one).

You however cannot inject variables into scopes you don't "own", you cannot access the scope of the `obj.func1` closure from the function reference - you need to put your code in that scope beforehand.

You might however use properties instead of variables, something like

```
var obj = {
    func1: function() {
        return this.$("h1");
    }
};
// later:
obj.$ = require("jQuery");
obj.func1();
```

Answer (score 0):

What @bergi said is correct. A different solution might also be to use Function.bind in one way or another:

```
var obj = {
  func1: function() {
    return this("h1");
  }
};
obj.func1 = obj.func1.bind(require('jQuery'));
// later:
obj.func1();
```